# Angular showing issue ... not getting proper

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am new to angular JS. Please take a look. This is my app.js file

```
angular.module("CrudDemoApp",["CrudDemoApp.controllers","ngRoute"]);
```

this is my controllers.js file

```
angular.module("CrudDemoApp.controllers", []);
controllers("MainController", function ($scope)
{
    $scope.message = "Main Controller";  
});
```

this is the my body part

```
<body ng-app="CrudDemoApp">
<div ng-controller="MainController">
{{message}}
</div>
</body>
```

firstly it is saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: controllers is not defined
at then it is saying 
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/ng/areq?p0=MainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module("CrudDemoApp.controllers", []) //remove semicolon here adding the controller to this module
  .controller("MainController", function ($scope) // dot before controller, remove "s"
  {
      $scope.message = "Main Controller";  
  });
```

notice the dot and lack of pluralization on controller

You should have probably seen some other errors before the ones you mentioned always work from the first one down sometimes 1 error causes the next.